# Elasticsearch using my PostgresSQL database

Tags: node.js, postgresql, elasticsearch

By default Elasticsearch seems to query its own database in the indexes defined during the search.

Is it possible that Elasticsearch is not querying its database but mine in PostgresSql?

Answer (score 1):

No.

Elasticsearch is a database on its own rights, it's not an interface/middleman for other backends.

If you want to conditionally query different databases, you need to implement that logic at application level.